# How to skip over a unique userID and access its children values for a recycler view

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have created a `RecyclerView` that shows information about locations I have saved in Firebase. Each location is saved within a unique userID but I want the `RecyclerView` to show ALL locations regardless of which userID they are saved in.

My database looks like this

```
User Locations
---ih4flEIASsgs7tk5tFSBFNw1R8U2
------Bay tower lounge
-----------name
-----------location
------China Sichuan
-----------name
-----------location
---juh972y271bhw281732h2j31h2hh
------Greene lounge
-----------name
-----------location
------Hotel Canal
-----------name
-----------location
```

I want to display results such as bay tower lounge, china sichuan, green lounge, hotel canal regardless of the long userID.

I successfully have implemented a recycler view that displays the locations a user has posted but i dont know how to post all locations regardless of user.

```
public void startListening() {
        FirebaseUser user = mAuth.getCurrentUser();
        String userID = user.getUid();
        Query query = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance()
                .getReference()
                .child("User Locations")
                .child(userID)
                .orderByChild("time")
                .limitToLast(20);


        FirebaseRecyclerOptions<LocationInformation> options =
                new FirebaseRecyclerOptions.Builder<LocationInformation>()
                        .setQuery(query, LocationInformation.class)
                        .build();
        FirebaseRecyclerAdapter adapter = new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<LocationInformation, UserViewHolder>(options) {
            @Override
            public UserViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
                // Create a new instance of the ViewHolder, in this case we are using a custom
                // layout called R.layout.message for each item
                View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
                        .inflate(R.layout.feed_layout, parent, false);

                return new UserViewHolder(view);


            }

            @Override
            protected void onBindViewHolder(UserViewHolder holder, int position, LocationInformation model) {

                holder.setName(model.name);
                holder.setRating(model.rating);
                holder.setAddress(model.address);
                holder.setTime(model.time);

                //holder.setRating(model.rating);

                final String name = getRef(position).getKey();
                //final float rateValue = getRef(position).getKey();


            }
        };
        mRecyclerFeed.setAdapter(adapter);
        adapter.startListening();

    }
```

I am a beginner and under time pressure so please please if u can help me can u please leave a reply with a detailed and specific description of how i can fix this? thank you so much :)

UPDATE:

I have added this code which is meant to loop around my database and return all the locations for each of the users BUT it is just returning the locations of one user - this user is actually not the user i am logged in as so i know it is close to working but not completely. can someone please point out what i need to change to ensure ALL users locations are posted not just one user? thank you!!! :)

'''''''

```
private void getPastUserIds(){
    //locationReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("User Locations");
    locationsDatabase.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange( DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            if(dataSnapshot.exists()){
                for(DataSnapshot locations : dataSnapshot.getChildren()){
                    startListening(locations.getKey());
                }
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });
}
```

''''

Comment: You're calling `.orderByChild("time")`, but in the data structure you shared, none of the nodes have a `time` property. But aside from that: the `FirebaseRecyclerAdapter` from FirebaseUI is designed to show a list of child nodes. It cannot show a nested structure like yours. So you will have to create your own adapter for that.

Comment: time is a variable in my database i just forgot to put it in there when i was recreating my database for the question. sorry, can u pls help me with the updated code?? @FrankvanPuffelen

Answer (score 0):

Try to get `User Locations` child this way :

```
//Declare a local variable userList 
ArrayList<String> userList = new ArrayList<String>();

 FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        for (DataSnapshot ds : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
            //child = your userID
            String child = ds.getKey();
            userList.add(child)
        }
    }
```

Now that you have a list of all userID you can do a loop on that list and run your query

**Edit :**

```
public void startListening(String user) {
        FirebaseUser user = mAuth.getCurrentUser();
        String userID = user.getUid();
        Query query = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance()
                .getReference()
                .child("User Locations")
                .child(user)
                .orderByChild("time")
                .limitToLast(20);
                  ......   
                  .....
```

Comment: ignore last comment, i think i figured out some of the loop. Please see my updated question as i am very close to solving it but need your help please!!!

Answer (score 0):

The most simple and efficient solution I can think of would be to duplicate your data. This practice is called *denormalization* and is a common practice when it comes to Firebase. For a better understanding, I recommend you see this video, [Denormalization is normal with the Firebase Database](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vKqXSZLLnHA).

So in your case, you should create a new node in your database named `allUserLocations` and add there all locations regardless of user. Your new node should look like this:

```
allUserLocations
------Bay tower lounge
-----------name
-----------location
------China Sichuan
-----------name
-----------location
------Greene lounge
-----------name
-----------location
------Hotel Canal
-----------name
-----------location
```

If you also have a `time` property, you can use it in your query to order your locations.

Also, when you are duplicating data, there is one thing that need to keep in mind. In the same way you are adding data, you need to maintain it. With other words, if you want to update/detele an item, you need to do it in every place that it exists.